# ax2550 node fails to connect to ax2550?

Tags: ros, ros-hydro, ubuntu-precise, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I'm using a ROS driver for the ax2550 motor controller found here:

https://github.com/wjwwood/ax2550

(I couldn't figure out the actual download, so I just created my own project and copied the text into each file, then catkin_made.  I don't think this is the source of my problems, since it compiled, and worked for a similar device driver that I got working just yesterday.)

I have plugged the device into a serial-->usb converter, which then goes into my computer. However, when I run the node using:

rosrun ax2550 ax2550_node /dev/ttyUSB0 (this is the port its connected to)

I get the following response:

```
[ INFO] [1405371811.620859117]: AX2550 connecting to port /dev/ttyUSB0
[ERROR] [1405371811.621207096]: Failed to connect to the AX2550: IO Exception (13): Permission denied, file /tmp/buildd/ros-hydro-serial-1.1.7-0precise-20140617-0339/src/impl/unix.cc, line 150.
[ INFO] [1405371811.621317396]: Will try to reconnect to the AX2550 in 5 seconds.
```

It looks like this is a permissions error (despite the fact that I am the administrator), but I don't know for sure and if it is I don't know how to change these permissions. Anyone got any ideas?

Thanks

New info:

I ran the line sudo chmod 777 /dev/ttyUSB0, which solved the error I was initially having. However, I am now encountering a new error when I try to run the node:
[ INFO] [1405453884.235150040]: AX2550 connecting to port /dev/ttyUSB0 [ERROR] [1405453886.236099864]: Failed to connect to the AX2550: Synchronization Exception: did not receive an R/C message after reset, file /home/randy/catkin_ws/src/toro/src/ax2550.cpp, line 315. [ INFO] [1405453886.503068921]: Will try to reconnect to the AX2550 in 5 seconds. Any idea what could be causing this one?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/186558/ax2550-node-fails-to-connect-to-ax2550?/) by [mysteriousmonkey29](https://answers.ros.org/users/9531/mysteriousmonkey29/) on ROS Answers with karma: 170 on 2014-07-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-07-15**:
You can use 'git clone URL' to create a local copy of the repository (see also the 'HTTPS clone url' box at the bottom right on the repository page. You might benefit from following a tutorial on git(hub), such as http://readwrite.com/2013/09/30/understanding-github-a-journey-for-beginners-part-1.

**Comment by [mysteriousmonkey29](https://answers.ros.org/users/9531/mysteriousmonkey29/) on 2014-07-15**:
Thanks.  I checked this out and it is a much easier method of installing github stuff

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2014-07-15**:
@randylewis7 if you are still having trouble getting this to work you might update your question with new information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Make sure you have dialout access. Try `sudo chmod 766 /dev/YOURPORT`. A colleague of mine had a similar issue.

---

Originally posted by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) with karma: 2549 on 2014-07-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mysteriousmonkey29](https://answers.ros.org/users/9531/mysteriousmonkey29/) on 2014-07-15**:
That did the trick, thanks.  I ran the line

sudo chmod 777 /dev/ttyUSB0, which solved the error I was telling you about initially. However, I am now encountering a new error when I try to run the node:

[ INFO] [1405453884.235150040]: AX2550 connecting to port /dev/ttyUSB0
[ERROR] [1405453886.236099864]: Failed to connect to the AX2550: Synchronization Exception: did not receive an R/C message after reset, file /home/randy/catkin_ws/src/toro/src/ax2550.cpp, line 315.
[ INFO] [1405453886.503068921]: Will try to reconnect to the AX2550 in 5 seconds.

Any idea what could be causing this one?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No need to sudo on the port. As tonybaltovski suggests you only need to be in the dialout group.
I had a similar issue with the iRoomba create 2 and I fixed it by doing:

> sudo adduser <*your-username*> dialout

and **very,very,VERY important:** don't forget to logout and login back on your machine for the changes to be applied :)

---

Originally posted by [RagingBit](https://answers.ros.org/users/3460/ragingbit/) with karma: 706 on 2016-10-20

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [EpicWolverine](https://answers.ros.org/users/28947/epicwolverine/) on 2017-01-04**:
Thanks. This is a better solution than chmod-ing after every reconnect and a more secure solution than changing the permissions on the port in general.